# Outlook Inspector.Activate Method Not Bringing Window To Foreground

Tags: vba, outlook-2010

I'd like to make sure Reminders in Outlook 2010 actually pop up when they are fired.

I'm working on a cleaner implementation than the one discussed in the SE question [How to make Outlook Calendar reminders stay on top in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/251963/how-to-make-outlook-calendar-reminders-stay-on-top-in-windows-7/462453#462453)

I'm having finicky results when calling the [`Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869361(v=office.14).aspx) method, which should *activate an inspector window by bringing it to the foreground and setting keyboard focus.*

I'm calling `Activate` on what should be the Reminder Inspector item.  This is **not** an issue with calling [`Application.ActiveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865654(v=office.14).aspx), which returns *nothing if no Outlook explorer or inspector is open*, because I'm handling for nulls and displaying a message box in the event it can't find anything.

```vb
'ensures all reminder notices receive focus
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem Then
        If Not (Application.ActiveWindow Is Nothing) Then
            Dim myOutlook As Object
            Set myOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If myOutlook.ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMinimized Then
                'This works fine
                Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate
            Else
                'This call won't set window ontop
                Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When the code calls `Activate`, if outlook is minimized the activated window will be pulled to the front and receive focus, but if it's in open in the background it won't.

Do I really have no other option than to call user32 in order to set the z-index of the alert window?

Comment: To clarify - your problem is the `Reminders` window is not shown on top of other windows when Outlook is NOT minimized initially?

Comment: Does adding `myOutlook.ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMinimized` to your `else` statement work? This will flash Outlook for a second but I believe achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does `ActiveExplorer.Display` do it?

Comment: @enderland, yes, I'm looking for the Reminders window to pop up.  As I said, it's been finicky.  I tried both of your solutions and they worked, but then took them out and it was still working, so I'll have to wait until it's being problematic again to test it.  I'm not sure what's affecting the variable performance, but it must be something.

Comment: *(I don't use Outlook VBA at all, so this comment may be well off the mark.)*  Why are you setting a reference (i.e. `myOutlook`) to an Outlook application that may, or may not, be the one you are currently running your code in, and then why are you using the state of the `ActiveWindow` in that instance of Outlook to decide what to do with `ActiveExplorer` in the current instance?